# creating table with python/sqlalchemy with enum type column

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

The error comes from the line 16 ('gender = db.Column(db.Enum(Gender), nullable=False)') of the following code.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .views import app
import enum

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Gender(enum.Enum):
    female = 0
    male = 1
    other = 2

class Content(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum(Gender), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, description, gender):
        self.description = description
        self.gender = gender


def init_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(Content("THIS IS SPARTAAAAAAA!!!", Gender['male']))
    db.session.add(Content("What's your favorite scary movie?", 
Gender['female']))
    db.session.commit()
    lg.warning('Database initialized!')
```

And I get this error stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fbapp import app
  File "__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "models.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Content(db.Model):
  File "models.py", line 16, in Content
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum(Gender), nullable=False)
  File "sqltypes.py", line 1296, in __init__
    self._enum_init(enums, kw)
  File "sqltypes.py", line 1332, in _enum_init
    length = max(len(x) for x in self.enums)
  File "sqltypes.py", line 1332, in <genexpr>
    length = max(len(x) for x in self.enums)
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Could someone tell me where is my mistake ? thanks.

Comment: which version of sqlalchemy are you using?

Comment: I'm using sqlalchemy 1.2.3

Comment: interesting, that should work after 1.1

Comment: Are you using the [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) backport?  The original `enum` package is not the same as the one in the stdlib.

Comment: I'm using this one http://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum/ installed by pip install enum

Answer (score 0):

Create the enum using python Enum. Then reference it in your db migration using SQLAlchemy enum. Make sure they are named differently, otherwise you'll have a collision

```
import Enum as e
from SQLAlchemy import Column, Enum

class Animal(E):
   DOG = 1
   CAT = 2

class Animals():
   __tablename__ = 'animal_names',
   name = Column(Enum(Animal, name='animals'), default= Animal.DOG)
```

Also for whatever reason, when using Enums the default attribute works but server_default does not.